# Pintos: Not able to run due to loop caused by init_ram_pages

Tags: c, infinite-loop, boot, pintos

I am new to Pintos. I have downloaded Pintos and installed all the necessary dependencies on my Ubuntu linux. My system is EC2 system with the following ubuntu version

`Linux ip-172-31-23-62 6.2.0-1017-aws #17~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 17 21:07:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When I run `pintos run alarm-multiple` it goes in infinte loop. It seems to be encountering error while accessing `init_ram_pages` variable and so it is not able to print the following line from the file `threads/init.c`

```
printf ("Pintos booting with %'"PRIu32" kB RAM...\n",
          init_ram_pages * PGSIZE / 1024);
```

I have added another printf which just prints the value of `init_ram_pages` and that also fails.

In both cases, the pintos starts from the beginning again and encounters the error again and this happens forever.

Any idea why accessing the variable `init_ram_pages` is causing this problem?

Doing `nm` on start.o shows this -

```
nm threads/start.o
000000e8 n gdt
00000100 n gdtdesc
00000106 N init_ram_pages
         U main
00000000 N start
```

Not sure why `init_ram_pages` is marked as `N` I have modified the code to put it in `.data` section and that changed the `nm` output as follows -

```
nm threads/start.o
000000e8 n gdt
00000100 n gdtdesc
00000000 D init_ram_pages
         U main
00000000 N start
```

But still the error is same.

I really appreciate any help here. Thanks in advance.

I have described all the things I tried in the previous section.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using "qemu" to run Pintos.